# Nestjs accepting also application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: json, nestjs, x-www-form-urlencoded

We have a service which is calling our nestjs microservice with header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which seems not to be parsed as expected.

If we start also from a clean nestjs project and put this pice of code in the **AppController**

```
  @Post()
  async store(@Body() request: any) {
    console.log('request', request);
  }
```

If we send data to the service with curl in this way:

```
curl -d '{"abc": 123 }' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -X POST http://localhost:3000
```

At the end our console.log shows as that we don't have a valid json, the whole content of the body is puted in the first parameter of the request json, which is resulting in this

```
request { '{"abc": 123 }': '' }
```

As you can see the content is not parsed right to the json, the documentation is not showing a lot of the parser, but googling this should work out of the bax

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either post

- URL encoded data and claim it is URL encoded data *or*
- JSON encoded data and claim it is JSON encoded data

You're posting JSON and claiming it is URL encoded, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: we had to write it in the right way, which means -d 'abc=123', we thought tat putting the header will curl transform the data from json to url encoded ... which isn't so and also this probably would not make sense, if curl in background is doing something you probably also not would